# Change Custom Sort Icon for custom sort function in Datagrid MUI -React

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

In my requirement there are six column headers with sorting functionality in Datagrid of MUI, out of six two require custom sorting, I have created a custom sort function and which is working fine, the issue is with sorting icon, the icon is changing with using slots but for all the header title its showing same icon either ascending or descending icon. Is there any way to keep a custom unsorted icon for header which is not used for sorting and ascending, descending icons for selected columns.

I have tried using slots to control the icon, but i am not able to get data to compare the selected column header for custom sort function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.